# How to map numbers in columns to strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file which has a column as such:

Numbers (Column Name)

1 10 11

1 10 13

1 10 12

1 15 23

Each Number in every row denotes a letter where 1 = 'a', 2 = 'b'... and so on.

How do I map each number of each row to a letter?

Thank you

dataframe.meal_swap.replace(mappings)

​

line       Value

0          NaN

1          NaN

2          NaN

3          NaN

4          NaN

```
     ...
```

3200    1 6 20

3201    1 6 21

3202    1 6 21

3203    1 6 21

3204    1 6 21

Name: meal_swap, Length: 3205, dtype: object

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary of all the mappings

```
mappings = {1: 'a', 10: 'b', 15: 'c', 11: 'd', 12: 'e', 13: 'f', 23: 'g'}
```

Use `pandas.DataFrame.replace`

```
df.replace(mappings)
```

Or, Use `pandas.DataFrame.applymap` to apply the map (Less efficient)

```
df.applymap(lambda x: mappings.get(x, pd.np.nan))
```

Comment: Yeah! Guess I missed that. It would simplify a lot and it's more efficient. Thanks for the help @anky

Comment: dataframe['meal_swap'].replace(mappings)

0          NaN

1          NaN

2          NaN

3          NaN

4          NaN

         ...  

3200    1 6 20

3201    1 6 21

3202    1 6 21

3203    1 6 21

3204    1 6 21

Name: meal_swap, Length: 3205, dtype: object


I just ran it, but it still shows the same output... am I doing it right?

Comment: Please improve your question by providing proper example. You might wanna refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples for clarification. @AqeelAhlam